# Geoserver: how to deal with overlapping labels on overlapping polygons

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld

I've got overlapping polygons with labels and looking for an opportunity to display them (labels) without overlaying.

[example screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zjXz.png)

Here are the options i've tried in SLD:

```
<TextSymbolizer>
    <Label>
        <ogc:PropertyName>my_label</ogc:PropertyName>
    </Label>
    <Fill>
        <CssParameter name="fill">#880015</CssParameter>
    </Fill>
    <VendorOption name="partials">false</VendorOption>
    <VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
    <VendorOption name="spaceAround">10</VendorOption>
</TextSymbolizer>
```